# Cannot call to Unity method from native iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a  method like below in my unity script.

```
public class PointerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void setUnit(string unit)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null or empty", nameof(unit));
            
        } 
        else
        {
            assignedUnit = unit.ToLower();
        }                              
    }
}
```

Then in my iOS `Viewcontroller` I am calling it like this

```
if([self unityIsInitialized])
    {
        [[self ufw] sendMessageToGOWithName: "PointerController" functionName: "SetUnit" message: "cm"];
        
    }
```

My problem is I am getting the following error.

> SendMessage: object PointerController does not have receiver for
> function SetUnit!

What is the reason for this? What is the wrong I have done? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Unity or the libraries involved, but I notice the `functionName: "SetUnit"` uses a capital 'S' and the declared method `setUnit` uses lowercase 's'. Is that intended?

Comment: @chadnt OMG you saved me.. I even double checked this but I saw as same every time :/. Thank you very much :) :)